# Why am I getting "x is not accessed pylance" error in line 3 and 14? How can I fix it?

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeXmi.png)

Beginner programmer here and I can't figure out why VS code is telling me that my variable is not defined when I defined it in line 3.

I tried to call main() and expected for the code to work.

Comment: The variable `x` is only defined in the function `main`. There is no access to `x` in the function `yesorno`. You could pass `x` to `yesorno` to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think x variable should pass to function yesorno

```
def main():
    x = plum()
    yesorno(x)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).